# Use htaccess to redirect an included file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, symfony

I'm working on a WordPress/Symfony project so for that I've to replace the content of **index.php** and **wp-load.php** but when there is a WordPress update it overwrite these two files.

I thought to create two new pages **index2.php** and **wp-load2.php** with the correct content and on **.htaccess** replaced the call to index.php with index2.php and it works fine but the problem is how can I automatically redirect (on .htaccess ?) calls to wp-load.php (which is included in some file and not directly called ex: *require( dirname(**FILE**) . '/wp-load.php' );*) to wp-load2.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't because that one is included *inside* of the web server and the PHP process. Only things that generate an actual HTTP(S) request will ever go through the logic, that'll then apply `.htaccess`.

Are you sure, you are on the right path here?

Comment: I'm using this bundle [link]https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't matter.

An `include()` or `require()`call will _literally_ include the other source file, without actually going through apache.

Think of it like this: There is apache sitting on a webserver, which gets the requests, and processes the URL and the config (which is partly in `.htaccess` in this case). Then, if it's (for example) a picture it serves that right away, if it's a PHP file then it passes the request to the php process sitting _inside/behind_ apache. Which in turn does the include.

It never actually hits the "front" of apache.